# Creating a rolling fixed panel from a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-manipulation

I am working on big data problem with data frame that looks like this. My aim is to create two aggregated versions of this dataframe such that for each date beginning from the year 2015 to present, the result counts the number of users who existed in the panel on that date and also existed in the panel year before.Apart from counting the number of such users for each date, I would also like to sum what these users spent on the current date and on the date a year before.A user is said to exist in the panel on a given date x if join1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hXjW.png)

Comment: Since I am new user , I didn't quite understand how to embed the attached image as a table in the dataframe.My apologies.

Comment: Can you try to spend some time on the formatting of your question? It shouldn't take long 5-10min and will help all the readers to quickly understand your question and give you a good answer

Comment: @user1527152 Yes , I would be more than happy to. Could you please tell me some resources that I may use to learn the formatting ?